# Dynamic Variable Insert in Button_tag from Application Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a button_tag that contains a call to action and a phone number for something that should read "Call Us at 1-800-000-0000."  I have the phone number stored as a variable in the application helper.  I'm having trouble merging it in.  This is what I've tried

View
Tried

```
<%= button_tag 'CALL #{phone_number}', {class: 'btn btn-u margin-bottom-20 form-center-button'} %>
```

Also Tried

```
<%= button_tag 'CALL <%= phone_number %>', {class: 'btn btn-u margin-bottom-20 form-center-button'} %>
```

Application Helper

```
def phone_number
    '1-800-000-000'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= button_tag "CALL #{phone_number}", {class: 'btn btn-u margin-bottom-20 form-center-button'} %>
```

Note the double quotes. If you want to interpolate variables in a string, you must use double quotes.

String concatenation would also work:

```
<%= button_tag "CALL " + phone_number, {class: 'btn btn-u margin-bottom-20 form-center-button'} %>
```